# Can someone explain the motivation behind 'normal neighborhood, normal coordinates' of a point in Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

[image: Definitions of normal neighborhood of a point, normal ball etc.]I am studying on my own from do Carmo's Riemannian-geometry text and in chapter 3, the author introduces 'normal neighborhood of a point in Riemannian manifold $M$ and normal neighborhood of $0 \in T_{p}M$ and then introduces normal coordinates around a point $p \in M$.

And then in subsequent topics the author frequently uses normal neighborhood, normal ball etc.in proofs.

Now, what I don't understand is, why do we need these special type of coordinate chart around a point and special type of balls?

It would be great if someone could refer me to some source or maybe explain here the motivation behind introducing such notions which is not clear just by reading the text.

Thank you!

Comment: How are these things defined?

Comment: Please see my edit, I've added an image directly from the book. It would've taken too long to type it all out.

Comment: These are in connection with geodesics. In general, the theorems that use these concepts may themselves help to get more information about them.. For a specific example, what is a maximal normal neighborhood of a point in the sphere?

Comment: For instance, suppose you want to prove that the Riemannian distance function defines the same topology on a connected manifold as the original manifold topology. Try to prove this yourself without using normal neighborhoods and see where you get stuck. Then read do Carmo's proof.

Answer (score 6):

The point here is that it is very difficult to find coordinates adapted to a Riemannian metric. Since curvature is a local invariant, you simply cannot find coordinates in which a metric has a prescribed form. Normal coordinates is about the best that on can do in that direction. They are adapted to the metric in the sense that in the central point the metric is approximated by the flat metric to first order (which is the best that you can do). However, they are well adapted to geodesics through the central point and hence to distances to that point. This is about as good as it gets.